# Collapse a list of column dyads by taking the difference of their values

Tags: r

It would take too much time explaining what I want to do, so I'll be intuitive and show through tables.

Suppose I have the following database:

```
df1 <- data.frame("X1" = 20,
                  "Y1" = 10,
                  "X32" = 46,
                  "Y32" = 12,
                  "X102" = -12,
                  "Y102" = 3)
```

```
X1 Y1 X32 Y32 X102 Y102
20 10  46  12  -12    3
```

As you notice, I have dyads of columns with same number, but with a different character. For example, X1 and Y1 differ in the letter, but are the same at the number. What I want to do is to collapse these dyads by subtracting the columns Y from their respective column X, which would give something like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame("1" = -10,
                  "32" = -34,
                  "102" = 15)
```

```
1      32    102
-10   -34    15
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_pattern = '(.)(\\d+)',
               names_to = c('letter','number')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = letter, values_from = value) %>%
  reframe(number, Y - X)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   number `Y - X`
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 1          -10
#> 2 32         -34
#> 3 102         15
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>